# Type 'FC<IProps>' is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Currently I'm integrating TypeScript to my React project and I have a problem.
The error is:
[image]

The HeaderContainer component is:

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo, useState} from "react";

import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

import HeaderUI from "../ui/HeaderUI";
import LogoContainer from "../../common/Logo/functional/LogoContainer";
import BalanceInformationContainer from "./BalanceInformation/functional/BalanceInformationContainer";
import RenderEmptyContainer from "../../common/RenderEmpty/functional/RenderEmptyContainer";
import AccountContainer from "./Account/functional/AccountContainer";

import {getHeaderViewUserSelector} from "../../../redux/user/userSelectors";

import styles from "./Header.module.css";

interface OptionProps {
    className?: string,
    target?: string,
    href?: string,
}

interface ILogoProps {
    className: string,
    target: string,
    href: string,
}

interface IBalanceInformationProps {
    balance_wdx: number,
    wdxPrice: number,
    usdtPrice: number,
}

interface IAccountProps {
    username: string,
}

export type HeaderOptionType = {
    id: number,
    component: React.FC<ILogoProps | IBalanceInformationProps | IAccountProps | {}>,
    props: OptionProps,
}

const HeaderContainer: React.FC = () => {
    const user = useSelector(getHeaderViewUserSelector);

    const headerOptions = useMemo<HeaderOptionType[]>(() => ([
        {
            id: 0, component: LogoContainer, props: {
                className: styles.Logo,
                target: "_blank",
                href: "http://wordlex.finance/"
            }
        },
        {id: 1, component: RenderEmptyContainer, props: {}},
        {
            id: 2, component: BalanceInformationContainer, props: {
                balance_wdx: user ? user.balance_wdx : 0,
                wdxPrice: user ? user.wdxPrice : 0,
                usdtPrice: user ? user.usdtPrice : 0
            }
        },
        {id: 4, component: AccountContainer, props: {username: user ? user.username : "Loading..."}},
    ]), [user]);

    return <HeaderUI headerOptions={headerOptions} classes={styles}/>;
}

export default HeaderContainer;
```

In the Logo's component IProps I've the same as in ILogoProps interface.
 I think the error is in there: 
component: React.FC<ILogoProps | IBalanceInformationProps | IAccountProps | {}>,

The LogoContainer is (one of four components):

```
import React from "react";

import LogoUI from "../ui/LogoUI";

interface IProps {
    href: string,
    className?: string,
    target?: string,
}

const LogoContainer: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
    return <LogoUI {...props}/>;
}

export default LogoContainer;
```

Please can you describe to me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your `IProps`, `className` and `target` props are optional, but in your `ILogoProps`, they are required. Please make them exactly the same.

Also, it's generally a better idea to not duplicate the code as much as possible, so a better solution would be adding an `interfaces.ts` file in your root-level folder, say, `constants` or `config`, and define the interface one time and reuse it in multiple places.

Comment: ok, if I make interfaces.ts for interfaces. How can I make interface names unique? For example, if I have 2 Button components in different directories, how can I differentiate it?

Comment: If you have different components with the same name, you'll most likely have different interfaces for them too, so you can define the interfaces inside each component. Only reusable interfaces should be defined in `interfaces.ts` file.